# What is the expressing difference between We ain't and We are not?

Tags: synonyms

When reading this post:

https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/51219/20039

I wasn't sure what the last 3 sentences actually are stylistic about.

So the question is as the title states.

What is the expressing difference between We ain't and We are not?

Comment: `aint` can be used as am not, are not, is not, have not, and has not. BTW, aint is informal while `are not` is the version you must use in a formal writing.

Comment: @mok so it is exactly the same thing? And so one just uses it to save spoken/written characters? Would this say out anything about the characters in the linked dialouge? When one keeps saying ain't while the other says are not?

Comment: As far as I know they mean the same. But, I have no idea why someone insists on using aint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ain't](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ain%27t) is a regional dialect word (Cockney, East London, UK- 1706) that started off as a contraction of **am not**, then was used to replace **is not**, **has not** and a few other things. It is relatively common in the UK and in the [US](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ain-t?q=ain%27t). There are other regional variations in the UK- **aiy** is used in the Black Country and **bain't** is used in the West of England.

These words are widely used in novels to suggest that a character lacks education: I suspect that's the point of the quote that you referred to.